# errorCode=INVALID_ZIP using Adobe PDF service API

Tags: html, css, angularjs, adobe

I am using Adobe PDF service API. I am trying to run our HTML zip file into a sample project but it giving an error "Invalid Zip" status code:400.

Comment: It's not clear what "run our HTML zip file into a sample project" means. We also have no way of knowing what's causing the 400 error because you haven't shown us what your HTTP request looks like. Please review how to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have created another zip archive of HTML file and other dependency files like CSS and js and pass it to the CreatePDFFromDynamicHTML.java file to create a PDF after executing

 mvn -f pom.xml exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.adobe.pdfservices.operation.samples.createpdf.CreatePDFFromDynamicHTML command it gives an error 

 

description ='The zip file provided has invalid content.; transactionId=kNWylwnmtNDbJf9ERkbjuE1Ou62467uv'; requestTrackingId='ZDdG1zgw5sKjMdnEGjvV8PAdUlJwwwNO'; statusCode=400; errorCode=INVALID_ZIP

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly the case that your ZIP file does not have an index.html file? Your ZIP file needs to have at least one HTML file which is an HTML file.